# Media Library in Sitecore gone from production instance

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

In the authoring instance the media library is still there but at some point in the last 12 hours, the production media library folder simply vanished.  The logs don't seem to be telling me anything, although I'm still looking.

I'm going to publish to resolve the issue, but I'm not sure how it happened in the first place.  Are there any specific media library configuration items that might cause this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there were no languages for the item.  Apparently, when you publish this way, it will delete the item from the target.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did it happen that there were no languages assigned?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any specific media library configuration items that might cause this to happen. Perhaps is there anyway done a unpublish, what should not be allowed because it's a protected item.

But,
Check of the "media library" folder is still a protected Item.
On a protected item you can not change the Publish restrictions, and it can not delete or move.

If not, in the top navigation choose "Configure" and Protect Item from the Attributes buttons.

Normal the "media library" folder is a protected item.